# Write variables in different columns?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to convert a file with only one column to a file with different columns.
In this initial file, I have 4 variables. Each variable write 10 lines, and I would like to have 4 columns of 10 lines.

Graphically:

What I have:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

What I would like to have:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: So you have one column and you want one column with different sorting? Or are there line breaks missing?

Comment: I have tried to use for i in $var1; do; echo $i; done. And also I have tried different syntax for "echo".

Comment: I want each variable in one column, but the columns should be at the same line.

Comment: I can write the variables in a column and put a break line within variables, but all in the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste` for this, if you save the variables' lines to their own respective files.

```
$ # generating example files:
$ seq 1 10 > file1
$ seq 11 20 > file2
$ seq 21 30 > file3
$ seq 31 40 > file4
$ # showing contents of the files:
$ cat file{1..4}
1 # first file
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11 # second file
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21 # third file
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31 # fourth file
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
$ paste file{1..4}
1   11  21  31
2   12  22  32
3   13  23  33
4   14  24  34
5   15  25  35
6   16  26  36
7   17  27  37
8   18  28  38
9   19  29  39
10  20  30  40
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
rows=$(wc -l $1 | cut -d " " -f 1)
elements=$(uniq $1 | wc -l)
list=$(sort -u $1)
i=0
while [ $i -lt $(($rows/$elements)) ]
do
         echo $list
         ((i++))
done
```

Save it to `transpose.sh` (for example), make it executable `chmod +x transpose.sh` and call it like `./transpose.sh input.txt`

Comment: I have 4 variables ($var1, $var2, $var3 and $var4). Each variable has 10 lines. My question is if it is possible to write each variable in a column, getting 4 columns of 10 lines. Thanks